# How to use defer for inline Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, laravel

I am developing a webpage in PHP with Laravel. I want to use the attributes "defer" or "async" for my javascript files, but I have a few problems.
In every document, I load a header which contains:

```
{{ Html::script('js/jquery.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}
{{ Html::script('js/bootstrap.min.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}

{{ Html::script('js/pjax.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}
{{ Html::script('js/jquery.cookie.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}
{{ Html::script('js/blur.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}
{{ Html::script('js/scrollbar.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}

<!--Form-->
{{ Html::script('js/parsley/parsley.remote.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}
{{ Html::script('js/parsley/parsley.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}
{{ Html::script('js/parsley/es.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}
{{ Html::script('js/icheck.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}

<!--Funciones-->
{{ Html::script('js/funciones.js', array('defer' => 'defer')) }}
```

If I give them the attribute async, the don't work properly because some of them are modular.
So I've tried with the defer attribute and I don't have this problem, but now I have a problem with the inline javascript, because it calls a function of the header. (This is at the bottom of the page).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) { 
    eval(document.getElementById("script_biblioteca").innerHTML);
});


//Scripts on back/forward
section = 'biblioteca';
url_section = "{{Request::root()}}/"+section+"/";

activar_menu('#menu_biblioteca');
buscador('#dinamic_search', '#main', section);

</script>
```

And the error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
ReferenceError: activar_menu is not defined
```

How can I fix that?
And, I am using the "defer" attribute properly?

Comment: It's not the same because I cannot use this method. I have a header which I use in every page and on the other side, I have specific functions in each page. So I cannot put the specific function in the top because the top is the same for every page. And also because I load views, and when I load the view of this page I just load the contain of the div main, so I have no access to the rest of the page.

Comment: And the proposed solution doesn't use defer or async so I guess is less "efficient"

Comment: @proyecthd I'm replying late and probably you already found a solution for this, but I added an answer that could help you to the link that jsalonen commented. It wouldn't require to modify anything on the header/footer, and it doesn't need jQuery to be included before the scripts (so no `$ is not defined`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to concatenate all scripts in a single script using Gulp.

That way you wouldn't have this problem and also wouldn't have to open multiple browser connections to download multiple js files.

[gulp concat scripts in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961142/gulp-concat-scripts-in-order)

Also you get the message below when you try to use Jquery but it is not loaded yet:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```